# C++ effective calculation

Tags: c++

which is the most effective way to calculate does double is equal to another double, does it less with 1 or greater with one of it.

**EDIT:**
Example 18 > 18, 17 and 19 - true; 5,5 > 5,5, 4,5, and 6,5 - true.

If 18 is is in range between 17 and 19 - return true. Else return false.

If 5,5 is equal to 5,5 or it is in range of 4,5 to 6,5 - return true. Else return false.
Code started:

```
bool inRange(double one, double two)
{
    return  (one== one);
}
```

Comment: What is `isRange()` supposed to do? Your description doesn't make it clear.

Comment: Could you make your question more clear? It's hard to understand the way it is.

Comment: Just use some tolerance factor (in this case `1.0`) when comparing floating points as one would normally do.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Additionally, your example is not helpful (it checks if `one` is NaN?). The most useful part of it is that it shows you haven't put any effort yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>

bool inRange(double dNumber, double dMiddle)
{
    return std::fabs(dNumber - dMiddle) <= 1;
}
```

Comment: make it fabs(dNumber and dMiddle). Other than than it seems fine :)

Comment: @AlexG `abs()` is overloaded for `double`, so it's completely ok.

Comment: I'd say `<math.h>` should be changed to `<cmath>`, since the first is deprected. Also, `std::` should be added to `abs`.